# YouTube IFrame Api stopped working in IE8 in August 201

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-8, youtube-iframe-api

the YouTube IFrame API stopped working in Internet Explorer 8 in August 2016. Please try the code below (just copy and paste it in a html page in your local server). It works fine in all browsers except IE8.

[This is the error in IE8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VokBw.jpg)

Could you please be able to suggest a solution or workaround? Highly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body onload='frmHelpVideo_startup();'>
<form method="POST" action=''>
    <div>LAUNCHING PLAYER IN 5 SECONDS (IT FAILS IN IE8. HOW TO FIX?) . . . </div>
    <div id='diviframeVideoHelp'></div>
</form>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var playerHelp = null;
function frmHelpVideo_startup(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){frmHelpVideo_player_init();}, 5000);
}
function frmHelpVideo_player_init(){
    playerHelp = new YT.Player  ('diviframeVideoHelp', {
        playerVars: {controls: 1, showInfo:0},
        events: {'onReady': Player_help_event_handler_ready, 'onStateChange': Player_help_event_handler_state_change, 'onError': Player_help_event_handler_error}
        }
    );
}
function Player_help_event_handler_ready(event){
    playerHelp.loadVideoById('1Ugle4aIous');
}
function Player_help_event_handler_state_change(event){
}

function Player_help_event_handler_error(event){
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2016/01/05/web-developers-rejoice-internet-explorer-8-9-and-10-die-on-tuesday/